# How to stop multiple Movieclips at a time by play/pause button in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 4 Movieclips in timeline.these movieclips have inner animation. they are classically tween in timeline. I have to stop and play these four movieclips at a time by play/pause button. Noted that, I have used the following code for that purposes.

It can stop only one MovieClip which is in the upper layer, and the rest 3 Movieclips can't be stopped by play/ pause button. (I have tried all movie clips are in same instance name and also tried with different instance).

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


var Playing: Boolean = false;
var lastPosition: Number = 0;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlayClick);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPauseClick);


function onPlayClick(event: MouseEvent):void {
    if (Playing == false) {
        Playing = true;
        first_sl.play();
        this.play();
    }
}


function onPauseClick(event: MouseEvent):void {
    Playing = false;
    lastPosition = this.position;
    first_sl.stop();
    this.stop();
}
```

Comment: You can stop your MovieClips as any other MovieClip : `mc1.stop(); mc2.stop(); mc3.stop() .... `.

Comment: i have tried... it works... but here is a problem is the main timeline can't be stopped by play/pause button as well as inner animation of these MovieClips in the timeline...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like when you are stopping main timeline with `stage.stop();` also use `mc.stop();` ect. and when u play them use `stage.play();` also `mc.play();`

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


var Playing: Boolean = false;
var lastPosition: Number = 0;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlayClick);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPauseClick);


function onPlayClick(event: MouseEvent):void {
    if (Playing == false) {
        Playing = true;
        mc.play();
        mc2.play();// other 2 mc's too
        stage.play();
    }
}


function onPauseClick(event: MouseEvent):void {
    Playing = false;
    lastPosition = this.position;
    mc.stop();
    mc2.stop(); // other mc's
    stage.stop();
}
```

And if you are using last position for timeline also use it for mc's so it will be sync..
hope this on help tho :)

Comment: I have tried & faced the compiler errors as following-                           Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 48 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method stop through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.

Comment: did u use this code inside a movieclip ? if it is u should target stage with MovieClip(root).stop();

Comment: No. i did use it globally... but it is noted that these four movieClips are also exist in timeline by separate layer and they are classically tween from same frame no. to same  stopped frame. and each mc consists of inner animation..

Comment: @HalilÇakar That's wrong, you can not use : `stage.play()` and `stage.stop()`.

Comment: sorry my mistake tho ^^ it should be just play() and stop()

Comment: Okey then i understand it now and @akmozo is just answer fine u could use that

Answer (score 0):

To stop the main timeline you can use `stop()` or `MovieClip(root).stop()` and to play it again, you can use `play()` or `MovieClip(root).play()` :

```
var playing: Boolean = false;

btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlayClick);
btn_pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPauseClick);

function onPlayClick(event: MouseEvent):void
{
    if (!playing) {       
        play();         // you can also use : MovieClip(root).play();   
        mc1.play();
        mc2.play();
        mc3.play();
        mc4.play();
        playing = true;
    }
}

function onPauseClick(event: MouseEvent):void
{
    if (playing) { 
        stop();        // you can also use : MovieClip(root).stop();
        mc1.stop();
        mc2.stop();
        mc3.stop();
        mc4.stop();         
        playing = false;
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.